# TCL performance test - why so much fluctuation?

Tags: tcl

I modified TCL8.4.20 source in the following files in order to measure the run time of TCL script:

1. basic utility
   Record the time:

> ```
> void save()
> {
>   struct timespec t;
>   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t);
>   save_to_an_array();
> }
> ```

2. tclMain.c, in Tcl_Main() function, before calling Tcl_FSEvalFile(), record time
3. tclBasic.c, in Tcl_EvalEx(), at the start, record time; there are multi exits, record time at each exit.
4. tclMain.c, before exiting Tcl_Main(), dump out all the recordings.
5. Build TCL source as usual and executable tclsh8.4 now has my builtin function to record the script run time and dump out the times at the end.

I use an one-liner script: `puts hello`

To my surprise, the run time varies greatly. Here is a consecutive time:

```
run1 - 232.00ms
run2 - 7886.00ms
run3 - 6973.00ms
run4 - 5749.00ms
run5 - 224.00ms
run6 - 6820.00ms
run7 - 6074.00ms
run8 - 221.00ms
```

Maybe bytecode version has better consistency? So I added more probes to Tcl_EvalObjEx and TclExecuteByteCode(). Here is the new script:

```
proc p {} {
  puts hello
}

p
```

But it is not consistent either:

```
run1 - 226.00ms
run2 - 7877.00ms
run3 - 6964.00ms
run4 - 5740.00ms
run5 - 218.00ms
run6 - 6809.00ms
run7 - 6064.00ms
run8 - 216.00ms
```

Do you see what might be the problem?

[***UPDATE***]
Maybe `puts` is a bad choice since it is I/O function which is impacted by many system issues, so I changed the script to some random commands:

```
set a 100
set b 200
append a 300
array set arr1 {one 1 two 2}
```

It definitely is better:

```
run1 - 9.00ms
run2 - 9.00ms
run3 - 19.00ms
run4 - 9.00ms
run5 - 9.00ms
run6 - 9.00ms
run7 - 9.00ms
run8 - 9.00ms
run9 - 9.00ms
run10 - 9.00ms
```

But again, how does that run3 at 19ms come from?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using wall-clock timing is that it is very sensitive to whatever else is going on on your system. The OS can simply decide to suspend your process at any moment on the grounds of having other “more important” work for the CPU to do. It doesn't know that you're trying to do performance measurements.

The usual way of fixing this is to both do many runs of the timing script and to take the minimum of the measured timings, bearing in mind that the cost of doing timing at all is non-zero and can have an effect on the output.

The `time` command in standard Tcl is intended for this sort of thing. Here's an example of use:

```
puts [time {
    set a 100
    set b 200
    append a 300
    array set arr1 {one 1 two 2}
} 100]
```

This runs the code fragment from before 100 times and prints the average execution time. (In my performance-intensive tests, I'll use a whole bunch of stabilisation code so that I get reasonable information out of even microbenchmarks, but all they're really doing is guessing a good value for the iterations and printing the minimum of a bunch of samples. Also, microbenchmarks might well end up with iteration counts in the hundreds of thousands or millions.)

---

Be aware that you're using a version of Tcl that has been end-of-lifed. 8.5 is the current LTS version (i.e., it mostly only receives security fixes — if any; we don't have many vulns — and updates to support evolving OS APIs), and 8.6 is for new work. (8.7 and 9.0 are under development, but still pre-alpha.)